# Python Lists - Create List, Sort, and Select First in One Line - Not Possible?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Desired code:

```
SmallestNumber = [ 5, 7, 3 ].sort()[0]
```

This however does not work.

What does work:

```
Numbers = [ 5, 7, 3 ]
Numbers.sort()
SmallestNumber = Numbers[0]
```

Is there any way to do this in one line?

It seems that the issue is related to [list].sort() returning a NoneType.

It seems that the sorted() function allows me to do this:

```
Numbers = [ 5, 7, 3 ]
SmallestNumber = sorted( Numbers )[0]
```

This would work for me but I would prefer to accomplish this with a single line if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For more simplicity try builtin function:

```
min([ 5, 7, 3 ])
```

3

Comment: Note to anyone attempting to also reverse this sorted list in one line - it appears that the max() function works as expected similar to this min() function.

Comment: The fun part comes with the `key` parameter of `min` and `max`. You want to know which of the numbers 2, 4, 8, 16, 32 is closest to 15? Here you go: `min([2, 4, 8, 16, 32], key=lambda x: abs(x - 15))`

Answer (score 1):

```
SmallestNumber = sorted([ 5, 7, 3 ])[0]
```

Comment: One difference to the original approach: `sorted` works, but it creates a new list. The `sort` method mutates the original list.